# Eclipse: auto execute and generate code on save

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation, auto-generate

I'm using Eclipse and I wanted to create a system that automatically generates java source code every time I save the project. More precisely I want to search for some files in a directory, generate static attributes for each of them and generate some methods every time the project is updated/saved. I thought that a piece of code that could be auto-executed by Eclipse would be fine, but I don't know if it's even possible. How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a program or Ant script to be run when a project needs building in the 'Builders' section of the Properties for a Project.

You can also write an Eclipse plugin 'Incremental Builder' using the 'org.eclipse.core.resources.builders' extension point. More information about this in the Eclipse help.

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to express what I want to do on save/clean in Java. That would give me more flexibility.

Comment: The builders run when you save and clean as long as you have 'Build automatically' checked

Comment: Yes, I was saying that I want to execute some Java code in those situations, not external programs or Ant scripts.

Comment: In which case you need to write an [Eclipse Incremental Builder](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FresAdv_builders.htm) in a plugin

Comment: Yes, I think that could do the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has an [extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_contributing_a_cleanup.htm) for cleanup and save actions that will be executed when you a save a file.

This requires implementing and installing a custom Eclipse plugin, so it's more intrusive than using a builder to run a script, but also more flexible, since you can use the JDT API to inspect the Java model of the given file.

Comment: This could let me run my own java code on save/clean? No other methods are possible?

Answer (score 0):

I personally use :https://github.com/mystilleef/eclipse4-smartsave
Just from marketplace eclipse4-smartsave or as on page other solutions.
Plugin sometimes hangs, still it is great.